# Logistic Regression in python. probability threshold

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

So I am approaching the classification problem with logistic regression algorithm and I obtain all of the predictions for the test set for class "1". The set is very imbalanced as it has over 200k inputs and more or less 92%  are from class "1". Logistic regression generally classifies the input to class "1" if the P(Y=1|X)>0.5. So since all of the observations in test set are being classified into class 1 I thought that maybe there is a way to change this threshold and set it for example to 0.75 so that only observations with P(Y=1|X)>0.75 are classified to class 1 and otherwise class 0. How to implement it in python?

```
model= LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=1) 
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
score=accuracy_score(y_test, model2.predict(X_test))
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, model2.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
roc=roc_auc_score(y_test, model2.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
cr=classification_report(y_test, model2.predict(X_test))
```

PS. Since all the observations from test set are being classified to class 1 the F1 score and recall from classification report are 0. Maybe by changing the threshold this problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thing you might want to try is balancing the classes instead of changing the threshold. Scikit-learn is supporting this via `class_weights`. For example you could try `model = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', class_weight='balanced', C=1)`. Look at the documentation for more details:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Do you know how to deal with the same problem in MLP classifier? the f1 score and recall are also 0 in this case.

Comment: If you are using keras for that, you can find an answer here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras. It works similarly. Scikit-learn's MLPClassifier does not support this. Alternatively, you could oversample the smallest class or undersample the largest.